# Sonata media bundle how to enable pixlr editing?

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin, sonata, sonata-media-bundle

I have enabled pixlr as described [here](https://sonata-project.org/bundles/media/master/doc/reference/extra.html) but is not enabled have tried many times. 
There is no edit with pixlr button visible in media form.

Am I missing anything, Struggling from long time. Please help,
Is there any additional config apart from this?

**Here is my config**

```
sonata_media:
    pixlr:
        enabled:  true
        secret:   theSecretHash
        referrer: Demo

    # if you don't use default namespace configuration
    class:
        media: App\Application\Sonata\MediaBundle\Entity\Media
        gallery: App\Application\Sonata\MediaBundle\Entity\Gallery
        gallery_has_media: App\Application\Sonata\MediaBundle\Entity\GalleryHasMedia
        category: App\Application\Sonata\ClassificationBundle\Entity\Category

    db_driver: doctrine_orm # or doctrine_mongodb, doctrine_phpcr it is mandatory to choose one here
    default_context: default # you need to set a context
    contexts:
        default:  # the default context is mandatory
            providers:
                - sonata.media.provider.dailymotion
                - sonata.media.provider.youtube
                - sonata.media.provider.image
                - sonata.media.provider.file
                - sonata.media.provider.vimeo

            formats:
                small: { width: 100 , quality: 70 }
                big:   { width: 500 , quality: 70 }            
        gallery: 
            providers:
                - sonata.media.provider.dailymotion
                - sonata.media.provider.youtube
                - sonata.media.provider.image
                - sonata.media.provider.file
                - sonata.media.provider.vimeo
            formats:
                original: { width: 500, quality: 100 }
                thumbnail: { width: 200, height: 200, quality: 100 }

    cdn:
        server:
            path: http://127.0.0.1:8000/uploads/media # http://media.sonata-project.org/

    filesystem:
        local:
            directory:  "%kernel.root_dir%/../public/uploads/media" #flex
            #directory:  "%kernel.root_dir%/../web/uploads/media" #non-flex
            create:     false
```

Answer (score 1):

After digging into the code I found the problem is with Symfony 4 making services private by default.

And this is how sonata media bundle enables pixlr

First it checks if `sonata.media.extra.pixlr` service is available in the container.
If not then it doesn't enable the pixlr. Since the service is private container is not able to access the service.

```
// Sonata\MediaBundle\Twig\GlobalVariable

/**
 * @return Pixlr|bool
 */
public function getPixlr()
{
    return $this->container->has('sonata.media.extra.pixlr') ? $this->container->get('sonata.media.extra.pixlr') : false;
}
```

Workaround for this is to override service definition and make it public :)

```
sonata.media.extra.pixlr:
    public: true
    class: Sonata\MediaBundle\Extra\Pixlr
    arguments: [~,~,"@sonata.media.pool", "@sonata.media.manager.media", "@router", "@sonata.templating", "@service_container"]
```

Now you can see pixlr edit button enabled in media form